# Is it possible to share Identity/Auth from MVC application to a virtual app WebAPI in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have an MVC application running on IIS. It has a WebAPI project running as a virtual application. My MVC is configured to use the Identity framework. Is it possible to pass the authenticated user into the WebAPI controller?

Comment: Are you using .Net or Core? Are you using a auth provider?

Comment: .NET Framework - auth provider is mostly Identity framework with Entity Framework

Comment: You want to share auth cookies and machine keys between your apps: https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2019/09/part-2-share-authentication-cookie.html